# C++ Sending PNG File via HTTP

Tags: c++, http, server

I'm trying to create a webserver to learn how HTTP functions.  I am trying to send a png file to the browser, however the image successfully makes it.

Here is my png sending code:

```
std::ifstream in("P:/server"+location, std::ios::binary);

if(!in.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "failed to open file" << std::endl;
    in.close();
}
in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int length = in.tellg();
in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

char *data = new char[length];

in.read(data, length);

in.close();

std::string headers = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\rContent-Length: " + std::to_string(length) + "\n\rConnection: keep-alive\n\rContent-Type: image/png\n\r\n\r";

int totalLength = headers.length() + length;
char *allData = new char[totalLength];
std::strcpy(allData, headers.data());
std::strcat(allData, data);

int bytes = send(socket, data, totalLength, NULL);
```

Once the server should have sent the image, it shows up as the missing image icon.

I have checked to make sure that all the bytes are being sent, and that the image is being loaded.
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"  Please post an [mcve] along with whatever problem you've observed.

Comment: HTTP standard calls for `\r\n` instead of `\n\r`.

Comment: strcat? Really? PNG is not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes in your code.

1. You are still trying to process the file if `is_open()` returns false.
2. You are using `\n\r` when you need to use `\r\n` instead.
3. You are using `strcat()` to append `data` to `allData`.  When appending binary data, like a PNG, `strcat()` will truncate on the first `0x00` byte encountered. You need to use `memcpy()` (or equivalent) instead.
4. Your call to `send()` is sending `data` when it should be sending `allData` instead. So you are you not sending the HTTP headers at all, and you are sending `data` using the wrong length.
5. You are assuming `send()` will send all of the data you give it in a single operation. That is almost never the case, especially fo large amounts of data.  `send()` returns the number of bytes it actually accepted for sending, so you need to call it in a loop until all of the data has been accepted.
6. You are not sending an error message to the client if something goes wrong while preparing the file.

That being said, `allData` is actually unnecessary, and is a waste of memory. TCP is a byte stream, so you can send `headers` and `data` individually one after the other.  How many times you call `send()` doesn't affect how the other party receives  the data.

You might also consider minimizing memory usage further by changing `data` to be a fixed-sized buffer so you can `send()` the content of `in` while reading from it in smaller chunks.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int sendData(int sckt, const void *data, int datalen)
{
    const char *ptr = static_cast<const char*>(data);
    while (datalen > 0) {
        int bytes = send(sckt, ptr, datalen, 0);
        if (bytes <=0) return -1;
        ptr += bytes;
        datalen -= bytes;
    }
    return 0;
}

int sendStr(int sckt, const std::string &s)
{
    return sendData(sckt, s.c_str(), s.size());
}

...

std::string filename = "P:/server"+location;

if (!fileExists(filename)) // <- you need to implement this
{
    if (sendStr(socket, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n") == -1) {
        close(socket);
    }
}
else
{
    std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "failed to open file" << std::endl;
        if (sendStr(socket, "HTTP/1.1 500 Error\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n") == -1) {
            close(socket);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        std::size_t length = in.tellg();
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

        if (in.fail())
        {
            std::cout << "failed to get size of file" << std::endl;
            if (sendStr(socket, "HTTP/1.1 500 Error\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n") == -1) {
                close(socket);
            }
        }
        else if (sendStr(socket, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: " + std::to_string(length) + "\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n") == -1)
        {
            close(socket);
        }
        else if (length > 0)
        {
            char data[1024];
            do
            {
                if (!in.read(data, std::min(length, sizeof(data))))
                {
                    close (socket);
                    break;
                }

                int bytes = in.gcount();
                if (sendData(socket, data, bytes) == -1)
                {
                    close(socket);
                    break;
                }

                length -= bytes;
            }
            while (length > 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *At least* two.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely the problem!